# whois-rb gem produces error: "Whois::ServerNotFound"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, whois-ruby

I'm totally lost here. I was trying to set up the whois gem according to the documentation at https://whoisrb.org/. Unfortunately I'm always getting an error when trying to perform a whois, locally on my machine.

Error message:

> Unable to find a WHOIS server for `;; answer received from 192.168.178.1 (75 bytes) ;; ;; security level : unchecked ;; ->>header<<- opcode: query, status: noerror, id: 51102 ;; flags: qr rd ra cd; query: 1, answer: 1, authority: 0, additional: 1 opt pseudo-record : payloadsize 512, xrcode 0, version 0, flags 32768 ;; question section (1 record) ;; google-public-dns-b.google.com.    in  a ;; answer section (1 record) google-public-dns-b.google.com.  84453   in  a   8.8.4.4 '

Don't get confused, I'm using the dnsruby gem as well.. The corresponding code in my model:

`def set_isp
    res = Resolver.new
    a_record = res.query(self.domain_name)
    whois = Whois::Client.new
    rec = whois.lookup(a_record)
    self.isp = rec.name
end`

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error, the issue is that you are passing the result of

```
a_record = res.query(self.domain_name)
```

straight to

```
whois.lookup
```

but the content of the `a_record` is not a domain name. Instead, it's a full DNS response:

```
;; answer received from 192.168.178.1 (75 bytes) 
;;
;; security level : unchecked
;; ->>header<<- opcode: query, status: noerror, id: 51102
...
```

Please make sure the input is a valid domain name (or IP address).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where did you go wrong I just try to create a sample apple using the [gem whoisrb](https://whoisrb.org/docs/v3/usage/) all I had to do is Add the whois gem to the Gemfile.

```
#Gemfile
gem 'whois', '~> 3.0'
```

Now you can open the console and type in

```
$ client = Whois::Client.new
$ response = client.lookup("google.com")
```

I created a example git project that will show you how its put together in the controller. I could and should it to a model method

https://github.com/mzaragoza/sample-whoisrb